# Help with real number proof strategy

Tags: inequality

Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb R$.  Prove that $\displaystyle \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \leq \frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|} + \frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|} \; $

Help on how to start with this one? Real lost.

Comment: This is not an abstract algebra question. I suggest you retag it as real-numbers.

Comment: yes real numbers, sorry

Answer (score 2):

How about trying to prove 
$${a+b\over1+a+b}\le{a\over1+a}+{b\over1+b}$$
first? It's a special case of the above, and so the simplest solution to your more complicated problem would at least have to solve this problem. Once we solve this example, see if the steps are easily modified to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What holds you from the setting of both sides to a common denominator? :-)